# Typescript: Convert optional properties to required non nullable except for some properties

Tags: typescript

I want to convert an object with optional properties to required nullable properties while keeping the required properties intact. If a property has the type NotNullable, it should not be null in the conversion.

For example:

```
type A {
   a: number;
   b?: NotNullable<boolean>;
   c?: boolean;
}
```

Calling OptionalToNullable utility type should give the following:

```
type B = OptionalToNullable<A>
/* 
   {
      a: number;
      b: boolean;
      c: boolean | null;
   }
*/
```

I have tried:

```
export type NotNullable<T> = T extends null ? never : T;

export type OptionalToNullable<O> = {
    [K in keyof O]-?: NotNullable<O[K]> extends NotNullable<infer V>
        ? V
        : undefined extends O[K]
        ? NonNullable<O[K]> | null
        : O[K];
};
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: What's the point of `NotNullable` on `b` in type `A`? Literally `b?: boolean` would do the same thing.

Comment: (Side note: I'd be **really** leery naming a custom type like `NotNullable` so similarly to the built-in type `NonNullable`. It's just asking to be misread...)

Comment: Do you realise that `NotNullable<boolean>` would just resolve to `boolean`? Defining a property of that type does not really make sense since you could just use `boolean`

Comment: This also kind of makes the transformation impossible since `b` and `c` are structurally identically as they are both optional with the type `boolean | undefined`. There is nothing to differentiate them so you should not expect a different output type.

Answer (score 2):

```
// use unique symbol to prevent collision
declare const unique: unique symbol

// use this type to "mark"(by union) a key so you can differentiate it and run extra operation on it
// in this case, key with this type will not union with null
type CannotBeNull = typeof unique

// find optional key by comparing X to Required<X>
type FindOptionalKey<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Required<T>[K] ? never : K }[keyof T]

// Remove the optional key, we are going to rebuild them later
type OmitOptionalKey<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = Omit<T, FindOptionalKey<T>>

// Remove CannotBeNull after it serves its purpose
// also remove undefined type
type RemoveSpecialType<T> = Exclude<T, CannotBeNull | undefined>

// check whether the key is marked with CannotBeNull
// if so do not union with null
type IsUnionWithSpecialType<T> = Extract<T, CannotBeNull> extends never ? T | null: T

// Rebuild the omitted optional key
type RebuildOptionalKey<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = { [K in FindOptionalKey<T>]: RemoveSpecialType<IsUnionWithSpecialType<T[K]>> }

// just to make the type look nicer in hint, does not change the result or what so ever
// without it, the type look like OmitOptional<A> & { b:string, c: boolean | null } instead of  {a: number, b:string, c: boolean | null } 
type Prettify<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }

// finally combine all the keys
type ConvertOptionalToNullUnion<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = Prettify<OmitOptionalKey<T> & RebuildOptionalKey<T>>

type A = {
   a: number;
   b?: string | CannotBeNull;
   c?: boolean;
}

type D = ConvertOptionalToNullUnion<A>
//   ^?
```

[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFcGcFMIOwJYEdy0gTwLYCMD2AbUAF11AAcAnaAN2jiNAGMD8FIFc4AoAE2kfwBDKk06QG4RCmgAueMlSgMOAly4gIMYgAs2xdGVglQAIkzCA1iYAU2dPM4BKUINAXo9yKXS5wTQXCgPAgAZiHQVPQIgkSwCAwBPKAUkqDQAB5EFK64htlEHIGcoPHqYAiBRLqQ-jAANG4eoADu8do6ekQGsK34hHC4EojFrVWgcOB9XF2GoADCAQNEAELQAHKThAC8+oa4IfLSahohFUm5BZyChO72dqKYZMIVAOagABrEpABK0CgIVB4AB53gA+abdUAAMTOAHkyJc4NcANIeIEAFTSmToPBqv2YFGB4gorwakgsA2acFBoNAOwA3qAANrIkqBW77UDogC6AFoAPxydEs7lY2JwXGgX7-QEY0Ei0D88Y0CKgOSsgC+TI5Bx5xzAv0wuFoOlgF0K10a6AazVgwlgL1wry+yWg2HACHwSSq0EwoCEsQoENmsMw8XhiJRaMxGXFkvxuEJQOJpPgFNwVJpdNAofiGIaMIlEYt+FR6Dl4LKUt9xtgCzgS1WGz6LhCgZKDBgFFoNXiNTI4AoZFwMCr1y8rqNJskfFOcGg3u6wdghtrAGVDIxovh0d05dmAKLpATgPj5+aLQZNzagAA+8FnFQXlY0jG0-AsLXfPoopqtJRqcwKHcJJRnaetG3WTYq1CJRSB4UglgcQIwPGaCZlgABJSAAFVhjgAB1NoN34bdd0MfcdiPLJBEYIhzwgq8oL6WlYxxGp51oX8lUxe8Jj6IV9Wrd1PW9d9QFwMMiFic4ERLK1l2Ej0vWLK5S2jMV2OrAkiSyVNyUpalaQZZlWQqaE4TktSyzlbk5FXWgSK3a5yOgIFsLwwoiKqJyyL3YVkW5LMNSEgArKAGGMcx3D-DD-VwXBP0QRhVXM3R6AaBDoA4wYmG0AIXiMcSqEgSYGETL8YjgtIuKrMDfAYeIGh9XZYHwBLP1YGLcyIVSkXwIEAEFaQAMlARlsBkFM4BeBpGDkPACGgAI7zQlsNTZcRlvOA5xsEOQJhwCIGkm6bZqYBaEvwZbAj4m8NsUgAFKhpNCcsY2xCU8X4RNdJJGayTgdNM2M8bTLZK1OR5IUFRCqs52ufB7GYHAnxcFsWtuSBFLmTguN6qz+vRXBm3wTzOAxTSvu037kz0gG00MrMdme6BXpCcser6qN3tGpTRO59TecrOLBuzekuFAKX9rQo6KAAbklqXsEFJR6bee9GJWZj8EVqWmFVxbroCRW4bigARbNcbgfHBeJ0nybgIbwQ0KWAD1+SAA)

Comment: Code dumps aren't generally **useful** answers. Please take the time to explain what you did, why, and how it works.

Comment: I **really** wouldn't call a new type `NonNullAble`, given it only differs from [the built-in `NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) by the capitalization of the `a`.

Comment: I agree with that, he should use another name

Comment: I will add explanation later, I am very sleepy now

Comment: ?? The OP's type is `NotNullable`, not `NonNullAble` (but yes, they should use a different name entirely).